# Access Report - sum frtTons only when extendedFreight > 0 in an expression

Tags: ms-access-2016

Access Report - sum frtTons only when extFreight > 0 in an expression
Hello, I would like to calculate the sum of frtTons only for rows where the extFreight is > 0.
How do I do this in an expression for the textbox for Grand Total frtTons?
[image: Access Report sum frtTons]

Answer (score 0):

Use an expression like this for a textbox on each line:

```
=Sgn([extFreight])*[frtTons]
```

Then sum this textbox.

Or, just sum using this expression:

```
=Sum(Sgn([extFreight])*[frtTons])
```

Comment: This expression asked me to put in extFreight instead of calculating frtTons. Do you have anymore suggestions? just to Clarify, I want to sum frtTons only when extFreight is > 0 for each line on the report.

Comment: Yes, see alternative method, please, added to the answer.